# How to set pitch in default view (Cesium 1.35)

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm trying to set a default pitch for the HomeBotton Widget.

```
  var home = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(11.34176,45.47452,17.60577,49.41534);
  var heading = 0.0;
  var pitch = Cesium.Math.toRadians(-45.0);
  var range = 0.0;
  Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE = home;
  Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_OFFSET =  Cesium.HeadingPitchRange(heading, pitch, range);

  var geeMetadata = new Cesium.GoogleEarthEnterpriseMetadata({
    url : 'http://openg.kartenwerkstatt.at/Austria3DSmall'
  });

  var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    imageryProvider : new Cesium.GoogleEarthEnterpriseImageryProvider({
        metadata : geeMetadata
    }),
    terrainProvider : new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
        url : '//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world'
    }),
    vrButton: true,
    animation: false,
    baseLayerPicker : false,
    homeButton: true,
    infoBox: true,
    geocoder: true,
    sceneModePicker: false,
    selectionIndicator: false,
    timeline: false,
    sceneModePicker: false,
    navigationHelpButton: true,

  });
```

Setting the default view with Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE works fine. But I didn't manage to figure out how Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_OFFSET is supposed to work.

So my Cesium map ends up looking a bit dull [Cesium without pitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzjHY.jpg) while it could look like [Cesium with Pitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLhsg.jpg) with ease.

Comment: did you ever come up with a resolution? I am looking for the same thing currently.